# Trying to connect an HOC

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, connect, higher-order-components

Im trying to use user roles to determine whether or not to display a component. So im trying to use an HOC to handle that functionality, but im getting an error i dont quite understand. here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { getUserRoles } from 'modules/api/account/user/selectors';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const RestrictedOrFallBack = ({
    wrappedComponent,
    role,
    userRoles,
    fallback,
}) => {
    if (userRoles.includes(role)) return wrappedComponent;
    return fallback;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userRoles: getUserRoles(state),
});

const ConnectedRestrictedOrFallback = connect(mapStateToProps)(RestrictedOrFallBack);

export { RestrictedOrFallBack };
export default ({
    role,
    fallback = () => (<div />),
}) => WrappedComponent => (
    <ConnectedRestrictedOrFallback
        role={role}
        fallback={fallback}
        WrappedComponent={WrappedComponent}
    />
);
```

The error im getting is: `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Connect(RestrictedOrFallBack) />`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: updated code according to answer

```
import React from 'react';
import { getUserRoles } from 'modules/api/account/user/selectors';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'utility/compose';

const RestrictedOrFallBack = ({
    wrappedComponent,
    role,
    userRoles,
    fallback,
}) => {
    debugger;
    if (userRoles && userRoles.includes(role)) return wrappedComponent;
    return fallback;
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    userRoles: getUserRoles(state),
});

const ConnectedRestrictedOrFallback = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    RestrictedOrFallBack,
);

export { RestrictedOrFallBack };
export default ({
    role,
    fallback = () => (<div />),
}) => wrappedComponent => ConnectedRestrictedOrFallback({
    role,
    fallback,
    wrappedComponent,
});
```

Comment: in `RestrictedOrFallback` you should be returning `fallback()` not `fallback`

Comment: That didnt seem to fix it. If im not mistaken returning fallback will be returning a functional component, which is what I want.

Comment: do you try createElement or React?  like this: `createElement(fallback, props)`? Looks like fallback and wrapped are not pure functions returning something valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "connect" an HOC.  "connect" *returns* an HOC itself and HOC's can only be applied to actual components.

What you are trying to do is [compose](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) 2 HOCs to form a new HOC.

so you would do something like:

```
import { connect, compose } from 'redux';

const ConnectedRestrictedOrFallback = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    RestrictedOrFallback
);
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the userRoles doesnt get propagated down, see updated code in edit.

Comment: did you solve your problem?  I didn't look close enough at how you were using your ConnectedRestrictedOrFallback and so don't think my answer was quite right.